# Prove this identity: $\cos x(\sec x-\cos x)=\sin^2x$

Tags: trigonometry

I have been trying to prove this identity for about 25 minutes and I can't figure it out. Can you help me please?

$$\cos x(\sec x-\cos x)=\sin^2x$$

Comment: Just multiply the left-side out, using the fact that $\cos x \sec x = 1$. This should give an extremely familiar identity.

Answer (score 1):

See that $\sec x-\cos x=\frac{(1-\cos^2x)}{\cos x}=\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos x}$

Now if you multiply it by $\cos x$ then you get your answer $\sin^2x$.

Comment: You should type using Math-Jax to make your posts more appealing. Read this http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: can you edit my post please...

Comment: i donnot know it thats why...

Comment: Again: read the examples in the link *and learn*. It's not hard.

Comment: look i tried to do it but its not coming in the desired way after reading that....

Comment: Then try again...and again and again. Giving up so quickly is not a good sign in someone trying to learn mathematics...

Comment: its about editing not about mathematics..

Comment: one thing speaks of the other...and also *at least* in one of your other questions (the one about the limit) you seem to want all given to you, without giving a problem a serious, real thought. Don't bother answering this as I won't continue, I just hope you think of this a little.

Answer (score 1):

Note that by the definition of the `secant`: $$\color{blue}{\sec x = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}}$$
So rewriting $\sec x$ as $\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ in your question, we have:

$$\cos x\left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{\cos x}}-\cos x\right)=\sin^2x$$

By the distributive property we can multiply the $\cos x$ in the sum (or difference), then we'll get:

$$1-\cos^2 x = \sin^2x$$

This is true because of the identity:

$$\sin^2 x + \cos^2x = 1$$

Answer (score 0):

Cos(x)(sec(x)-cos(x))=cos(x)(1/cos(x)-cos(x))=cos(x)((1-cos^2(x))/cos(x))=cos(x)(sin^2(x)/cos(x))=sin^2(x). Where sec(x)=1/cos(x) and cos^2(x)+sin^2(x)=1.